# How to access Gmail's "Send" button using Selenium RC for Java or C# or Python

Tags: c#, java, python, gmail, selenium-rc

I have tried this probably 6 or 7 different ways, such as using various attribute values, XPath, id pattern matching (it always matches `":\w\w"`), etc. as locators, and nothing has worked. If anyone can give me a *tested, confirmed-working* locator string for this button, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emulate a click on the button, just go to `#compose`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python, use the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) library and access Gmail's HTML version.  The **Send** button is simply a form submit button.

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://htmlversionofgmail.com/composewindow")

br.select_form(nr=0) # select the first form
# Do some stuff, fill out the subject, whatever.
response = br.submit()
```